# Ubuntu 16.04,MySQL 5.7.19,Unable to delete database

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I am new to MySQL and in the learning curve , 
I wanted somehelp ..

I tried importing the temp database from https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db ... I am having diffulties in importing the same .

I think I have wrongly imported and I wanted to drop the table , But its not allowing me .
I get the below error .

```
mysql> show databases;
+-------------------------+
| Database                |
+-------------------------+
| information_schema      |
| mysql                   |
| performance_schema      |
| sys                     |
| #mysql50#test_db-master |
+-------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am not getting any response in Terminal , but when I tried in MySQL Workbench , I am getting the below error

```
*drop '#mysql50#test_db-master'
22:04:30    drop '#mysql50#test_db-master'  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''#mysql50#test_db-master'' at line 1   0.00034 sec*
```

I wanted to delete this table & wanted to create a new one again ...

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-database.html shows the syntax for `DROP DATABASE`.

Pro tip: **Read documentation.** You can get answers more quickly than by posting on Stack Overflow.